# Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Below is my script

```
CREATE TABLE alrashed.tbl_alerts_details (
    alert_id int,
    action_required int,
    alert_agent_id int,
    alert_agent_type_id int,
    alert_agent_type_name text,
    alert_definer_desc text,
    alert_definer_name text,
    alert_source text,
    alert_state text,
    col_1 text,
    col_2 text,
    col_3 text,
    col_4 text,
    col_5 text,
    current_escalation_level text,
    date_part date,
    device_id text,
    driver map<text, text>,
    is_processed int,
    is_real_time int,
    location map<text, text>,
    seq_no int,
    severity text,
    time_stamp timestamp,
    transporter map<text, text>,
    transporter_name text,
    trip_id int,
    updated_on timestamp,
    vehicle map<text, text>,
    vehicle_type_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (alert_id)
    ) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 }
    AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE'
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0;
```

when I'm running this query I'm getting

> Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed) error

Here is my cassandra query in Java:

```
select
  count( * )
from
  tbl_alerts_details
where
  alert_state = 'ACKNOWLEDGE'
  and date_part >= '2017-10-01'
  and date_part <= '2017-10-31'
  and is_real_time = 1
  and alert_agent_type_name = 'VEHICLE' ALLOW FILTERING
```

Comment: Could you please check the Cassandra log to see if it has any errors. For example if it has something like this: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/spark-connector-user/ZKyACqzoBw4/32UIoxyVFgAJ

Comment: i checked cassandra logs it is showing Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM alrashed.tbl_alerts_details WHERE alert_state = ACKNOWLEDGE AND date_part >= 2017-08-01 AND  LIMIT 5000' (last scanned row partion key was (185587)); query aborted

Comment: That's a lot of tombstones. You should probably rethink your data model. If it suits your use case it would be possible to lower the gc_grace_seconds on your table (but you have to understand what this means otherwise it could be really bad for you and data could reappear after deletion). 
If you're new to Cassandra I could point you to some great learning resources.

Answer (score 5):

This error had made us realise a space issue for us, storing images in Base64 in every row had quickly made the `Tombstone` problem arise.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772581/4088428),

> Cassandra doesn't just scan through the rows, but also has to
>   accumulate them in memory while it prepares the response. This can
>   cause an out-of-memory error on the node if things go too far out, and
>   if multiple nodes are servicing the request, it may even cause a
>   multiple failure bringing down the whole cluster. To prevent this from
>   happening, the service aborts the query if it detects a dangerous
>   number of tombstones.